# J syntax for canonical sorting?

Tags: j

I am sorting through some J code, and happened upon this line of code:

```
] { /:@~.
```

I am trying to understand its use and function. Could someone help me read it, or use it? There is a label on it that states it is a canonical function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest, I am not exactly sure what your section of code is trying to do. Is it possible that it is part of a larger tacit verb?

In the meantime, there are parts that certainly could be useful in sorting the unique items of a vector.

```
   ~. 3 4 5 2 3 4     NB. returns the unique items of a vector
3 4 5 2
   /:@~. 3 4 5 2      NB. returns the indices that will order that vector
3 0 1 2
     3 0 1 2  { 3 4 5 2 NB. using { to select indices 3 0 1 and 2 from the vector.
2 3 4 5
    (] {~ /:@~.) 3 4 5 2 3 4 NB. perhaps this is what your code should have been?
2 3 4 5
```

The parenthesis around `] {~ /:@~.` are important as they make the three verbs, `]`,`{~` and `/:@~.` into a fork which takes `]` and `/:@~.` and makes them into the left and right arguments to `{~` The adverb `~` reverses the left and the right arguments of the verb `{`. The right argument we know is `/:@~.` which are the unique indices `3 0 1 2` and the left argument is `]` which is the original list `3 4 5 2 3 4`. Reversing the two would be equivalent to

```
     3 0 1 2  { 3 4 5 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
```

So, perhaps you meant `(] {~ /:@~.)` which would sort the unique items of a vector?

Hope this helps.

Comment: `(] { /:@~)` is an (odd?) way to sort an unsorted `i.n` array.

Comment: `(] { /:@~)` I think is a syntax error because `/:@~` is a verb conjunction adverb construct and that doesn't really make sense. My preferred way of expressing this would be to use the hook `({~ /:@~.)` but I was looking for a form that was closer to the original phrase.